# Flask app posting data to the wrong resource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have a search button that when clicked, should send data to my server. The javascript looks like this:

```
$('#search-btn').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/my_route",
        data: JSON.stringify({title: 'hallo', article: 'test'}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.title);
        console.log(data.article);
        },
      });
    });
```

On the server, my routing looks like this:

```
@app.route('/my_route')
def route(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print(request.method)
    return flask.jsonify({"foo": "bar"})
```

With this setup, I get a console error from jQuery: `POST http://localhost:5000/ 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)`

I don't understand why this code is throwing a 405 ad posting data to wrong resource? Both the ajax and routing point to `/my_route`. Can anyone spot my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to put `methods=['GET', 'POST']` in the `app.route` decorator like such:

```
@app.route('/my_route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route():
    print(request.method)
    return flask.jsonify({"foo": "bar"})
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#http-methods

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Since this fixed your problem, would you mind accepting it as the best answer?